# Powershell on Windows 2019 doesn't wait for a statement

Tags: powershell

I've created a powershell script to prepare server disks some years ago and it was functioning all the time, but now using Windows 2019 I got a problem. This part of the script

```
#$disk_list = (Get-Disk | where { ($_.OperationalStatus -eq "Offline") -and ($_.IsClustered -eq $False) })
if ($disk_list)
{
    Write-Host "$($disk_list.count) disks with partition style RAW are found" -ForegroundColor Green
    $overview_disks = [pscustomobject]@{ }
    
    foreach ($d in $disk_list)
    {
        $LUN = Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | where { ($_.InterfaceType -eq "SCSI") -and ($_.index -eq $d.Number) } | select Name, SCSILogicalUnit, Size
        $overview_disks | Add-Member -Name $LUN.Name -Value $("`tLUN:" + $LUN.SCSILogicalUnit + " `tDiskID: " + $d.Number + " `tSize: " + $([math]::Round($LUN.Size /1GB, 1)) + "GB") -MemberType NoteProperty
    }
    $overview_disks
```

doesn't work anymore, delivering an empty object $overview_disks.
I got it functioning using Measure-Command:

```
$disk_list = (Get-Disk | where { ($_.OperationalStatus -eq "Offline") -and ($_.PartitionStyle -eq "RAW") })
#$disk_list = (Get-Disk | where { ($_.OperationalStatus -eq "Offline") -and ($_.IsClustered -eq $False) })
if ($disk_list)
{
    Write-Host "$($disk_list.count) disks with partition style RAW are found" -ForegroundColor Green
    $overview_disks = [pscustomobject]@{ }
    
    foreach ($d in $disk_list)
    {
        Measure-Command -Expression { $LUN = Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | where { ($_.InterfaceType -eq "SCSI") -and ($_.index -eq $d.Number) } | select Name, SCSILogicalUnit, Size} 
        $overview_disks | Add-Member -Name $LUN.Name -Value $("`tLUN:" + $LUN.SCSILogicalUnit + " `tDiskID: " + $d.Number + " `tSize: " + $([math]::Round($LUN.Size /1GB, 1)) + "GB") -MemberType NoteProperty
    }
    
    $overview_disks
```

Measure-Command lets $LUN= part to wait till it finishes.
I've searched a lot, but there is no information why it doesn't wait in a standard syntax of the script as it was the case for Windows 2012 and 2016.
Do one of you have an idea?

Comment: What is the output of your `$PSVersionTable`? Specifically the PSVersion and PSEdition? I ask because I can run the old version of your script on a 2019 server without the timing issues you're seeing. (using the built-in Desktop-v5.1)

Comment: Sometimes there can be timing issues when mixing output streams. You're using `Write-Host` at the beginning, then later running `$overview_disks` (basically `Write-Output`). Best practice would be changing `Write-Host` to `Write-Output`, but that's not likely to be the issue here.

Comment: `$_.index -eq $d.Number` this condition is rather off... Why is it here?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale output of $VersionTable:
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.4402
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.4402
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Comment: @AlexZelaya, it's where because it's a filter, server has a lot of disks, but I need only disks with ids collected in $disks_list